# How could I increment by 1 every 5th row whenever another row is the same?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data consisting of a building information.
Floor Floor_Area_Num.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| **Floor** | **Floor_Area_Num** |
| 001 | 1-1 |
| 001 | 1-2 |
| 001 | 1-3 |
| 001 | 1-4 |
| 001 | 1-5 |
| 001 | 1-6 |
| 001 | 1-7 |
| 001 | 1-8 |
| 002 | 2 |
| 002 | 2-2 |
| 002 | 2-3 |

I would like another column that can increment by 1 from 0 every 5th row (where the Floor Column is the same), but it should go back down to 0 when it is a new floor.
like so:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Floor** | **Floor_Area_Num** | **num** |
| 001 | 1-1 | 0 |
| 001 | 1-2 | 0 |
| 001 | 1-3 | 0 |
| 001 | 1-4 | 0 |
| 001 | 1-5 | 0 |
| 001 | 1-6 | 1 |
| 001 | 1-7 | 1 |
| 001 | 1-8 | 1 |
| 002 | 2 | 0 |
| 002 | 2-2 | 0 |
| 002 | 2-3 | 0 |

So, far I'm using this:
`=INT((ROW(C2)-2)/5)+1` which lets me increment 1 every 5th row.
But I am not sure how to change it back down to 0 when the Floor value changes.
Any advice?

Edited: not all Floor_Area_Num has hyphenated numbers.
Some floors also contain letters in the beginning, likeso:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Floor** | **Floor_Area_Num** | **num** |
| A01 | A101 |  |
| A01 | A102 |  |
| A01 | A103 |  |
| A01 | A104 |  |
| A01 | A105 |  |
| A01 | A106 |  |
| A02 | A201 |  |
| A02 | A202 |  |
| A02 | A203 |  |
| A02 | A204 |  |
| A02 | A205 |  |
| A02 | A206 |  |
| MB1 | MB101-A |  |
| MB1 | MB101-B |  |
| MB1 | MB101-C |  |
| MB1 | MB101-D |  |
| MB1 | MB101-E |  |

now reflecting the above, the Num column above should be as so:

```
+--------+-----------------+------+
|   A    |        B        |   C  |
+--------+-----------------+------+
| Floor  |  Floor_Area_Num |  num |
| A01    |  A101           | 0    |
| A01    |  A102           | 0    |
| A01    |  A103           | 0    |
| A01    |  A104           | 0    |
| A01    |  A105           | 0    |
| A01    |  A106           | 1    |
| A02    |  A201           | 0    |
| A02    |  A202           | 0    |
| A02    |  A203           | 0    |
| A02    |  A204           | 0    |
| A02    |  A205           | 0    |
| A02    |  A206           | 1    |
| MB1    |  MB101-A        | 0    |
| MB1    |  MB101-B        | 0    |
| MB1    |  MB101-C        | 0    |
| MB1    |  MB101-D        | 0    |
| MB1    |  MB101-E        | 0    |
+--------+-----------------+------+
```

Whenever it is a new floor, the num should be back to 0, as you can see above, and only increment by 1 after the 5th step of the same floor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `C2` try:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,0,INT((COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)-1)/5))
```

[image]

Comment: This seem to work! How could I edit this to fit floors with letters? for example, if I had B01 and also floors with SB1?

Comment: Can you expand your question with extra details @doh2122. Include desired behavior and results so I can understand what it is you mean. The answer does not even look at the 2nd column for the floor numbers.

Comment: will edit the question!

Comment: edited! the function you supplied works at the moment, but since some Floor value also contain letters, I would like to try to edit this function.

Comment: @doh2122, it works fine for me since all the function I supplied is to look if the value in column A is different to it's previous value. It doesn't matter if they are numeric or preceded by letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
=IF(IFERROR(LEFT(B2,SEARCH("-", B2)-1), "!")<>
IFERROR(LEFT(B1,SEARCH("-", B1)-1), "!"), 0,
IF(MOD(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(B1, LEN(B1)-SEARCH("-", B1))),5)=0, C1+1, C1))
```

First, we test to see if the floor changes. If it does, we restart at 0.
Next, we get the area number using normal string functions like `RIGHT`, `LEN`, and `SEARCH`. If the previous area was a multiple of 5, then we add 1 to the counter, if not, we repeat the counter.

For example:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It seems to be almost working. How about for places where I don't have a hyphen in the floor number?
`
1
1-1
1-2`
at the moment, I get error #VALUE! places I don't have the hyphen on the floor number.

Comment: If the cases of non-hyphens aren't consecutive, you can try wrapping the first test in an ```IFERROR```, see edit